# Best Way to Select Multiple Records GridView Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

```
Private Sub GetSelectedBasketRecord()
Dim j As Integer = 0

ViewState("SelectedBasket") = Nothing
For i As Integer = 0 To gvSapBaskets.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim rb As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvSapBaskets.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("CHKButton1"), CheckBox)
    If rb IsNot Nothing Then
        If rb.Checked Then

            Dim hf As HiddenField = DirectCast(gvSapBaskets.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("HiddenFieldBasketID"), HiddenField)
            If hf IsNot Nothing Then
                j = j + 1
                If j = 1 Then
                    ViewState("SelectedBasket") = "PositionID = " & hf.Value & " "
                Else
                    ViewState("SelectedBasket") = ViewState("SelectedBasket") & "AND PositionID = " & hf.Value & " "
                End If
                BasketIDLBL.Text = ViewState("SelectedBasket")
            End If

            If i = gvSapBaskets.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

I have checkboxes in a gridview,

- a user can select multiple check boxes
- Each checkbox has an ID assigned to it

Currently What i was planning to do was create an SQL query to bring back rows depending on what the user selects in the gridview, the viewstate would generate part of the SQL query

- if the user selects 1 row: ViewState("SelectedBasket") is `PositionID = 1234`
- if 2 rows are selected ViewState("SelectedBasket") is `PositionID = 1234 AND PositionID = 5678`

Then i was going to generate SQL like

`"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE " & ViewState("SelectedBasket") & "`

ViewState("SelectedBasket") would be something like `PositionID = 1234 AND PositionID = 5678`

I have a feeling there is probably a better way around this, just cannot think of it

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean OR instead of AND.

But a somewhat briefer approach would be to use IN:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PositionID IN (1234, 5678)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub GetSelectedBasketRecord()
  ViewState("SelectedBasket") = ""
  For Each gvRow in gvSapBaskets.Rows
      Dim rb As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("CHKButton1"), CheckBox)
      If rb IsNot Nothing Then
          If rb.Checked Then
              Dim hf As HiddenField = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("HiddenFieldBasketID"), HiddenField)
              If hf IsNot Nothing Then
                  ViewState("SelectedBasket") &= ViewState("SelectedBasket") & ", "
              End If
          End If
      End If
  Next

  If ViewState("SelectedBasket") <> "" Then
     ViewState("SelectedBasket") = Left(ViewState("SelectedBasket"), LEN(ViewState("SelectedBasket"))-2)
     ViewState("SelectedBasket") = "In (" & ViewState("SelectedBasket") & ")"
  End If
End Sub
```